# cmake build project once, install to multiple locations?

Tags: cmake

For building a large software project (composed of many cmake subprojects) I use one big cmake list with many `ExternalProject`s.

All subprojects build in pretty much the same way (`cmake --build ...` then `cmake --install ...`).

E.g.:

```
list(APPEND SUBPROJECTS subproject1) #later will pull dependencies from this list
ExternalProject_Add(subproject1
    DEPENDS item1 item2 ...
    GIT_REPOSITORY ...
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Source/subproject1
    CMAKE_ARGS ${COMMON_CMAKE_ARGS} ${COMMON_SUBPROJECTS_CMAKE_ARGS}
    BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Build/subproject1 --config ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
    INSTALL_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --install ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Build/subproject1 --config ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
    # common cmake variables instruct subproject's cmake to install
    # files in a directory under ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

Because the top-level project can be built in several "flavors", I have some cmake variables to control it, but only very few subprojects are actually affected by those variables.

Thus to build all the flavors I end up rebuilding the same stuff with the same flags multiple times, which is very inefficient.

It would be nice if I could **configure and build each subproject once** (well, only those that do not vary depending on the flavor), **but install it N times to N different locations**. I would then refactor the top-level project to build all flavors within the same build.

Is that possible? How?